# Regular expression to change decimal operator from comma to dot?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a bunch of insert queries in one text file retrieved from, let's say Oracle DB1. Now I have to execute the insert SQLs in another database,let's say Oracle DB2. Now the problem is the decimal separator in DB1 was "," but in DB2, it is ".". So I am getting error in DB2 during insertion as "invalid number". How can I change the decimal separator from "," to "." in notepad++. Following are 2 example of the insert queries.

```
Insert into schema1.tab1 (uniq_identifier,branch,INT_TYPE,NOM_RATE,EFF_RATE,FACTOR,START_DATE,END_DATE,BOOK_AMT,BOOK_FLG,LAST_BOOKED_DATE,INT_PAID_FLG,INT_PAID_AMT,WTAX_AMT,INT_PAYMENT_DATE,END_FLG,REVERSE_FLG,entity_id,create_user_id,creation_time,modified_user_id,modif_time,INT_PAID_TRAN_ID) values ('55000116754','BC000088','G','1.961','1.98','0,000054',to_date('22/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),to_date('04/07/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'1252,75','N',to_date('27/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'Y','1252,73','50,11',null,'Y','N','1000','FINADM',to_date('21/06/17 20:49:50','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'user1',to_date('27/06/17 22:01:20','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),null);

Insert into schema1.tab1 (uniq_identifier,branch,INT_TYPE,NOM_RATE,EFF_RATE,FACTOR,START_DATE,END_DATE,BOOK_AMT,BOOK_FLG,LAST_BOOKED_DATE,INT_PAID_FLG,INT_PAID_AMT,WTAX_AMT,INT_PAYMENT_DATE,END_FLG,REVERSE_FLG,entity_id,create_user_id,creation_time,modified_user_id,modif_time,INT_PAID_TRAN_ID) values ('55000065422','BC000008','G','1.961','1.98','0,000054',to_date('20/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),to_date('29/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'4586,34','N',to_date('27/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'Y','4586,36','183,45',null,'Y','N','1000','user1',to_date('18/06/17 08:03:49','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'user1',to_date('27/06/17 21:59:42','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),null);
```

Now if you see the queries, there are two amount fields with comma. In first query we have `'1252,73','50,11'` and in the second query, we have `'4586,36','183,45'`.

Comment: Try `\d+\K,(?=\d)` replace with `.`

Comment: Fastest method: `\d+\K,(\d+)` with replacement: `.$1`

Answer (score 1):

Search for `(\d),(\d)`.

Replace by `$1.$2`.

Here's a Javascript demonstration :

```js
var str = `Insert into schema1.tab1 (uniq_identifier,branch,INT_TYPE,NOM_RATE,EFF_RATE,FACTOR,START_DATE,END_DATE,BOOK_AMT,BOOK_FLG,LAST_BOOKED_DATE,INT_PAID_FLG,INT_PAID_AMT,WTAX_AMT,INT_PAYMENT_DATE,END_FLG,REVERSE_FLG,entity_id,create_user_id,creation_time,modified_user_id,modif_time,INT_PAID_TRAN_ID) values ('55000116754','BC000088','G','1.961','1.98','0,000054',to_date('22/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),to_date('04/07/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'1252,75','N',to_date('27/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'Y','1252,73','50,11',null,'Y','N','1000','FINADM',to_date('21/06/17 20:49:50','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'user1',to_date('27/06/17 22:01:20','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),null);`;

console.log(str.replace(/(\d),(\d)/g,'$1.$2'));
```

Comment: @Mistu4u `\d` is a digit. That searches for a comma sandwiched between 2 digits

Comment: and what does the `$` mean in this case?

Comment: @Mistu4u `$` is a capture group. `$1` returns what was captured in the first set of `()`

Comment: In some RE engines `\ ` is used instead of `$`: `\1`, `\2` and so on.

Comment: @Arkadiy Notepad++ also supports `\1` `\2`

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d\K,(?=\d)`
- Replace with: `.`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\d      : a digit
\K      : forget all we have seen until this position
,       : a comma
(?=     : lookahead, zerolength asszrertion, make sure we have:
  \d    : a digit
)       : end lookahead
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Insert into schema1.tab1 (uniq_identifier,branch,INT_TYPE,NOM_RATE,EFF_RATE,FACTOR,START_DATE,END_DATE,BOOK_AMT,BOOK_FLG,LAST_BOOKED_DATE,INT_PAID_FLG,INT_PAID_AMT,WTAX_AMT,INT_PAYMENT_DATE,END_FLG,REVERSE_FLG,entity_id,create_user_id,creation_time,modified_user_id,modif_time,INT_PAID_TRAN_ID) values ('55000116754','BC000088','G','1.961','1.98','0.000054',to_date('22/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),to_date('04/07/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'1252.75','N',to_date('27/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'Y','1252.73','50.11',null,'Y','N','1000','FINADM',to_date('21/06/17 20:49:50','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'user1',to_date('27/06/17 22:01:20','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),null);

Insert into schema1.tab1 (uniq_identifier,branch,INT_TYPE,NOM_RATE,EFF_RATE,FACTOR,START_DATE,END_DATE,BOOK_AMT,BOOK_FLG,LAST_BOOKED_DATE,INT_PAID_FLG,INT_PAID_AMT,WTAX_AMT,INT_PAYMENT_DATE,END_FLG,REVERSE_FLG,entity_id,create_user_id,creation_time,modified_user_id,modif_time,INT_PAID_TRAN_ID) values ('55000065422','BC000008','G','1.961','1.98','0.000054',to_date('20/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),to_date('29/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'4586.34','N',to_date('27/06/17 00:00:00','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'Y','4586.36','183.45',null,'Y','N','1000','user1',to_date('18/06/17 08:03:49','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),'user1',to_date('27/06/17 21:59:42','DD/MM/RR HH24:mi:ss'),null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to change anything in insert statements, since decimal separator is session specific parameter in Oracle and can be easily changed (i.e. see [this question on Ask Tom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9532776700346468197)).
Change `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` session parameter before executing the file (place following line at the very beginning of the file):

`alter session set NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ',.';`

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, but the SQLs are already shared by the other team and they are not ready to share it again because the file is quite large.